# Insert item in a comboBox in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

In my program i have 2 ComboBoxes as DropDown Lists. I would like to add items to the second ComboBox only after an item from first ComboBox has been selected.

So far i have this:

```
InitializeComponent();
comboBox1.Items.Add("Category1");
comboBox1.Items.Add("Category2");
comboBox1.Items.Add("Category3");
comboBox1.SelectedValueChanged += new EventHandler(comboBox1_TextChanged);

private void comboBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedText.Equals("Category 1"))
    {
        DataTable cat = dataTableAdapter.GetByCategory("category1");
        foreach (DataRow row in cat.Rows)
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Add(row.ItemArray[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're checking for "Category 1" instead of "Category1". Was that a typo in your example code?

Comment: A note from MSDN about using ComboBox.SelectedText and the DropDownList style: `If DropDownStyle is set to DropDownList, the return value is an empty string ("").` So perhaps you'll have to use the SelectedIndex or SelectedItem property instead (or change the style of ComboBox to one of the other types).

Comment: it is just an example code ...

Comment: @Jason thanks! It works just fine ! You may post it as an answer if you want to!

Comment: Cool Emil... I've moved my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A note from MSDN about using ComboBox.SelectedText and the DropDownList style:

`If DropDownStyle is set to DropDownList, the return value is an empty string ("").`

So perhaps you'll have to use the [SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex.aspx) or [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx) property instead (or change the style of ComboBox to one of the other types).

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedText.Equals("Category 1"))
```

To

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("Category1"))
```

Comment: Is is getting in the .equals if statement? If not what does the Debugger say comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() is